# How to plot a large dataset with more than 800,000 samples using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a dataset of *818,741* samples. values range between *0* and *7276*. I am using the following gnuplot script to plot the data.

```
#+begin_src gnuplot :var data=xtics :exports code :file file.png
  reset
  set term png 
  set output "data.png" 
  set title "Variations/entity"
  
  set xlabel "entity"
  set xtics rotate by -45

  set yrange [0:7276]
  set ylabel "# fo variations"

  plot 'sort_1.txt' u 2:xticlabels(1) w lp lw 2 notitle 
#+end_src
```

---

## Problem

The problem is that the cruve becomes a straight line when I use the dataset with the *818,741* samples.I cannot see the distribution of the data anymore. What plot do you suggest.

---

## Sample data

```
entity   # of variations
E0669803 7276
E0726485 496
E0679687 459
E0159288 395
E0018102 337
E0498282 333
E0349508 322
E0566375 315
E0096588 314
E0182788 313
E0595006 312
E0550909 291
E0338738 290
E0031352 290
E0409686 284
E0576457 279
E0277375 275
E0277379 0
```

[image]

---

## update

The following script is for the whole dataset. Well I don't think I can do any better.

```
#+begin_src gnuplot :var data=xtics :exports code :file file.png
  reset
  set term png 
  set output "data.png" 
  set title "Variations/entity"
  
  set xlabel "entity"
  set xtics rotate by -90

  set yrange [0:7276]
  set ylabel "# fo variations"

  plot 'data.txt'  u 2:xticlabels(1) every 100000 w lp lw 2 notitle
 
#+end_src
```

[image]

Comment: The question is: What are you expecting to read from the plot?

Comment: the distribution of variations/entity. the average number of variations per entity. the entities with the maximum and minimum number of variations. If i can plot an average curve. That shows where exactly the variations are distributed

Comment: How about a boxplot, or histogram/kernel density plot instead?

Comment: I don't know @ziggystar about these plotting  i'll look for them. I was looking for heatmap lol but don't know if I can do it with labels

Comment: If the number is too large then you can do `plot 'file.dat' using 1:3 every 10 with lines` to plot every 10th point. If your problem is that you cant see the small structures, then may be `set logscale y` counld help you. But I dont really understand your problem.

Comment: Well I just want to plot the histogram @JonatanÖström that's all for a large dataset

Comment: using every helped it's ok to use it. @JonatanÖström do you know anything about heat maps?

Comment: It's totally unclear why you want to plot a heatmap, since you apparently don't have 2-dimensional data.

Comment: No i dont. but searching the gnuplot 4.6 PDF documentation there are solutions. But you have only one-dimensional data, arent heat-maps for twodimensional data? Gnuplot has histograms, it might be `plot 'file.dat' using 1:2 every 10 with hist`, but google it if that doesn't work.

Comment: actually, `plot 'file.dat' using 2:1 every 10 with hist` might be what you need. to have the second column on the x-axis. Try it.

Comment: yes @JonatanÖström it worked and I still can see the distribution.

Comment: how can I set the number of bins?

Comment: You want an interval of values to be in the same bin? I dont know. But using 2:1 should reduce them considerably if I'm not misstaken.

Comment: @JonatanÖström What you recommend is wrong. Plotting `with histogram` doesn't calculate any histogram, but assumes you have appropriately preprocessed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract statistical data from your data sample, try boxplots, one for each `entity`:

```
set yrange [0:7276]
set style fill solid 0.25 border -1
set style boxplot nooutliers pointtype 7 separation 2
set boxwidth 1

plot "data.txt" using (1.0):2:(0):1 with boxplot notitle
```

This creates one boxplot for all data samples with the same string value in the first column, your "entity". And one boxplot for each unique entity is generated.